# How to upgrade tensorflow to 2.0 in google colab permanently

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to upgrade tensorflow to 2.x from the current existing version in google colab but each time i open the colab and check for its version it rolls back to the previous version (1.15.0). How to permanently upgrade the tensorflow to 2.x? since its taking lot of memory for installing each time. I have been trying the command !pip install tensorflow==2.1.0 each time the notebook is run since it is getting rollback to previous version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colab has two versions of TensorFlow pre-installed: a 1.x version and a 2.x version. Colab currently uses TensorFlow 1.x by default.

Running `import tensorflow` will import the default version (currently 1.x). You can use 2.x by running a cell with the `tensorflow_version` magic **before** you run import tensorflow.'

```
%tensorflow_version 2.x
```

Output:

```
TensorFlow 2.x selected.
```

Once you have specified a version via this magic, you can run `import tensorflow` as normal and verify which version was imported as follows:

```
import tensorflow
print(tensorflow.__version__)
```

Output:

```
2.1.0
```

If you want to switch TensorFlow versions after import, you **will need to restart your runtime** with 'Runtime' -> 'Restart runtime...' and then specify the version before you import it again.

```
%tensorflow_version 1.x
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
```

Output:

```
1.15.0
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. This really helps save me from downloading approx. 500 mb each time i want to use tensorflow in colab